# I can create 2 columns but not 3 columns using JSX with CSS in React

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx, spfx

I'm simply trying to create 3 columns of text fields with associated labels. I can easily create 2 columns but this code is putting the third text field on a row below:

```
 <div className={styles.threecol}>
       <div className={styles.col1}>
             <div style={{width: '150px'}}>
                 <Label className={styles.questionTitle}>Record No.</Label>
                     <TextField
                         value={this.state.Title}
                         disabled={true}
                      />
                   </div>
                 </div>

              <div className={styles.threecol}>
                 <div className={styles.col2}>  

                  <div style={{width: '150px'}}>             
                
                    <Label className={styles.questionTitle}>Room</Label>
               
                    <TextField
                      value={this.state.Room}
                      onChange={this._onRoomChange}
                    />
                    <br />
                  </div>
                </div>
               
              </div>
              <div className={styles.threecol}>
                 <div className={styles.col3}>   

                  <div style={{width: '150px'}}>               
           
                    <Label className={styles.questionTitle}>Room</Label>
              
                    <TextField
                      value={this.state.Room}
                      onChange={this._onRoomChange}
                    />
                    <br />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
             </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

The CSS:

```
.threecol {
      overflow: hidden
    }
    
    .threecol .col1 {
      width: 22%
    }
    .threecol .col2 {
      width: 22%
    }
    .threecol .col3 {
      width: 22%
    }
    
    .threecol .col1 {
      float: left;
    }
    
    .threecol .col2 {
      float: none;
    }
    .threecol .col3 {
      float: right;
    }
    
    .threecollabel {
      font:'24px';
      font-weight: 'bold';
      display: block;
    }

    .threecol .co1Sm {
      float: left;
      width: 200px;
      height: 30px;
    }
```

I can get two columns to show using the same technique with the CSS and JSX but not 3 columns.
Here's the JSX that works for 2 columns:

```
   <div>
      <div>
        <Label className={styles.questionTitle1}>Details</Label>
       </div>
        <div className={styles.twocol}>
          <div className={styles.col1}>
               
             <div style={{width: '150px'}}>
               <Label className={styles.questionTitle}>Record No.</Label>
                  
                 <TextField
                   value={this.state.Title}
                   disabled={true}
                  />
                </div>
               </div>
              <div className={styles.twocol}>
                 <div className={styles.col2}>               
                 
                  <div style={{width: '150px'}}>
                    <Label className={styles.questionTitle}>Room</Label>
                 
                    <TextField 
                      value={this.state.Room}
                      onChange={this._onRoomChange}
                    />
                    <br />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
             </div>
            </div>
```

I don't want to use tables.

T

Comment: Is it your intention to create nested `.threecol`? Because that's what you did: a `.threecol` with 3 child `.threecol`s...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Tom you are closing multiple `div` tag in your html. And then you are adding `float: none` to second column style `col2`. It may the issue.

```
.threecol .col2 {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Ref: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-3urqg6?file=index.html

Comment: That's great. It's weird how the 2 column worked with the JSX I've presented. What I think cracked it, was your provided CSS. Thanks.